# How to cast Rc<RefCell<Box<SomeType>>> to Rc<Box<SomeType>>?

Tags: rust, casting

I have a function that accepts an argument of `Rc<Box<SomeType>>` type and a variable of `Rc<RefCell<Box<SomeType>>>` type, and I can't get how to pass my variable into this function.

How to cast `Rc<RefCell<Box<SomeType>>>` into `Rc<Box<SomeType>>`?

Below is a pseudo code to be clear:

```
fn myfunc(a: Rc<Box<MyType>>) -> StructThatHoldsA {
    // Read-only usage
    StructThatHoldsA::new(a)
}

fn main() {
    let my_var = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Box::new(MyType::new())));
    let struct_with_my_var = myfunc(my_var.to_rc());
    // Mutating operations
    my_var.mutate_everything();
}
```

Comment: You can't borrow "as" a. `Box`. And you can't move out of the `RefCell`. So you can't.

Comment: Unless you are happy to destroy the `Rc<RefCell<Box<SomeType>>>`.

Comment: There is a deeper problem here: You could conceivable construct something around the idea of taking a parameter `U: Deref<Target=SomeType>`, because `Rc` and `Box` *can* deref directly to their inner `T`. But `RefCell` can't, which is the whole point of `RefCell`: It needs to check if the carried valued is currently borrowed mutably elsewhere before allowing access. So what you are asking is not just impossible due to types, but also due to behavior. You can't just "cast away" a `RefCell`; things would potentially break really really badly.